# Why am I missing soyDocs for my soy template?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates

Plovr is raises a compile-time exception when I try to compile this soy template.

```
// Copyright 2012 David Faux
/**
 * @overview Lays out the home page.
 */

{namespace templates.home}

/*
 * Lays out the home page.
 */
{template .main}
  <h1>Hi! Welcome to my experimental page.</h1>
  <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" id="homeLogo" />
{/template}
```

Here is the error raised.

```
org.plovr.CheckedSoySyntaxException:
template templates.home.main: Not all code is in Soy V2 syntax
(missing SoyDoc for template {template .main}).
```

Why am I missing soy docs for this template?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Closure Templates documentation for [file structure](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#filestructure) states:

> Precede each template with a SoyDoc comment that explains the purpose of the template, in the same style as JavaDoc.

JavaDoc comments must start with the begin-comment delimiter `/**` as shown in *How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool* under **[Format of a Doc Comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format)**.

The template example above is missing the second asterisk in the SoyDoc comment. It should look as follows:

```
/**
 * Lays out the home page.
 */
{template .main}
  <h1>Hi! Welcome to my experimental page.</h1>
  <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" id="homeLogo" />
{/template}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. to add more to [cpeisert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11497832/31671)  all following three comment lines should begin with first column, i.e. there should be no white space before all following three lines.

   ```
   /**
   * Lays out the home page.
   */
   ```
2. There should be no blank lines in the middle of these soy doc comment and soy code ( i.e.  `{template .main}`)
3. `{template .main}` should also starts from column1 , i.e. there should no preceding white space.